# Visual Studio C++ 2010 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express Edition and
I'm trying to compile an SDL project using the SDL_ttf.lib and get the following error messages:

```
1>SDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TTF_CloseFont referenced in function "void __cdecl DrawTextW(struct SDL_Surface *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)" (?DrawTextW@@YAXPAUSDL_Surface@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HHHHHHHHH@Z)

1>SDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TTF_RenderText_Shaded referenced in function "void __cdecl DrawTextW(struct SDL_Surface *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)" (?DrawTextW@@YAXPAUSDL_Surface@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HHHHHHHHH@Z)

1>SDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TTF_OpenFont referenced in function "void __cdecl DrawTextW(struct SDL_Surface *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)" (?DrawTextW@@YAXPAUSDL_Surface@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HHHHHHHHH@Z)

1>SDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TTF_Init referenced in function "bool __cdecl Init(void)" (?Init@@YA_NXZ)

1>SDL.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TTF_Quit referenced in function _SDL_main
```

I searched for solutions already but haven't found anything that solves my problem.
I didn't forget to link SDL_ttf.lib, I linked the folder with it also, included the header and put the SDL_ttf.dll into my projects folder.

P.S I have the same problem with SDL_image.

Answer (score 1):

usually that error is from the external object not being defined as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

like this

```
// LNK2019b.cpp
// LNK2019 expected
struct C {
   static int s;
};

// Uncomment the following line to resolve.
// int C::s;

int main() {
   C c;
   C::s = 1;
}
```

you probably need to define the actual instance of the _TTF object like SDL::_TTF_XXX

Comment: I eventually figured it out: Changed the include lib folder from x64 to x86 and that actually solved the problem, kind of stupid from me, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've got errors like this one before:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TTF_Quit
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _TTF_Init

because my project properties `Project|Properties|Configuration Properties|Linker|Input|Additional Dependencies` were missing:
"SDL.lib SDLmain.lib SDL_ttf.lib SDL_image.lib"